# Как на уровне nginx подменить урл?

Tags: php, nginx

Есть страница php, которая выводит шаблон, обращаться будут напрямую к php файлу, как подменить урл страниц (но чтобы php отработал нормально)? Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Пример: http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu.php

Comment: Подменить на что?

Comment: @D-side допустим на просто http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu

Comment: @D-side хотя бы убрать расширение в папке pages

Comment: Выработайте привычку дописывать детали о вопросе в сам вопрос.

Comment: @D-side спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**КОРОТКО**

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /pages/$1.php last;
    # ...
}
```

будет перенаправлять запросы с http://bla-bla.ru/urururu на http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu.php

```
server {
    # ...
    rewrite ^/pages/(.*)$ /pages/$1.php last;
    # ...
}
```

будет перенаправлять запросы с http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu на http://bla-bla.ru/pages/urururu.php

**Замечание**

Флаг **last** в конце директив **rewrite** значит, что данное правило, если оно применится будет последним в цепи обработки, данного пути и с ним больше никто ничего не сделает. Если данный флаг не поставить, то если путь будет соответствовать последующей директиве rewrite, то она его тоже обработает.

**Небольшой ликбез по регулярным выражениям**

`^/pages/(.*)$` - это регулярное выражение
Символ `^` - обозначает начало строки
Символ `$` - обозначает конец строки
Символ `.` - обозначает любой символ
Символ `*` после точки - квантификатор и обозначает количество символов, в данном случае - любое
Таким образом сочетание символов `.*` - означает любое количество любых символов
Символы `()` - применяются для группировки ряда символов, позже в замене ты сможешь обращаться к этим сгруппированным символам с помощью символа `$` и номера группировки
Соответственно, если у тебя несколько группировок 
Например `/users/(.*)/events/(.*)`
То ты сможешь обращаться к ним так:
`/event.php?user=$1&event=$2`
`$1`- первая группировка, `$2`- вторая группировка и т.д.

**ПОДРОБНЕЕ О ДИРЕКТИВЕ rewrite**

В NGINX есть модуль ngx_http_rewrite_module, который позволяет изменять URI запроса с помощью регулярных выражений PCRE, делать перенаправления и т.д.

**Синтаксис**:  `rewrite regex замена [флаг];`

`regex` - это регулярное выражение, на соответствие которому будет проверяться путь
`замена` - это тот путь на который стоит перенаправить запрос.
`[флаг]` - необязательный параметр, один из 4 флагов(last, break, redirect, permanent)

Если указанное регулярное выражение соответствует URI запроса, URI изменяется в соответствии со строкой замены.

**флаги**

`last` - завершает обработку текущего набора директив
`break` - завершает обработку текущего набора директив
`redirect` - возвращает временное перенаправление с кодом 302
`permanent` - возвращает постоянное перенаправление с кодом 301

**Контекст**:   server, location, if
Это значит что данная директива может находится в блоках

```
server{
    # rewrite ...
}
```

.

```
location * {
    # rewrite ...
}
```

.

```
if * {
    # rewrite ...
}
```

**БОЛЬШЕ ПРИМЕРОВ**

```
server{
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api.php?model=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/news/(.*)$ /news.php?slug=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/users/([\d]+)/notes/([\w_\-]+)$ /user_notes.php?user_id=$1&note=$2 last;
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 break;
    rewrite ^(/download/.*)/audio/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.ra  break;
}
```

Документация по ngx_http_rewrite_module:
https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: Михаил - Большое спасибо за Развернутый ответ.
Сколько не искал документации (понятной для меня) - Это Лучшая, печально что только по Одной Директиве.

Comment: @ВладиславВладимиров, спасибо. Приятно слышать.